# Access Drawn Features on Map with Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

[image]I'm starting to experiment with Puppeteer and it looks great for some of our needs to create screenshots and PDFs, but I'm trying to determine if I can use it to access features a user has drawn on a map (we're using OpenLayers but also applies to Google Maps, Leaflet, etc).

**Example:**

I can get a PDF of https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html but have no idea where to start with (or if I even should use) Puppeteer to capture what the user has drawn or if they've re-centered the map or anything else.

**Edit:**

Added Example Image of User Interaction. Can I capture the elements drawn with Puppeteer or would I need to save and remake them through Puppeteer commands if doing a PDF with Puppeteer.

Comment: It's still not clear what you are trying to get. Can you add some image examples showing the actual user behaviour you are trying to get?

Comment: I added an image and explanation of what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My (still growing) understanding of Puppeteer is that you have to remake the user interaction. This can be done by saving the features (to a cookie, file, database, etc.) and recalling them in an on load type event that is called when you want to use Puppeteer.  But since Puppeteer sends a new request to the page from the server it doesn't know about what the user has done at that point.